# Zf2 - ZfcRbac / AuthenticationService - Doctrine2

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfc-rbac

I'm using ZfcRbac to handle my authorization and Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService to handle authentication.

I've noticed in the Zend Developer Toolbar, each page request is showing 4 repetitive SQL queries.

1) Query users table based on user_d

2) Query rbac_role based on role_id

3) Query rbac_role based on parent_role_id

4) Query rbac_role_permissions

My identity object is stored in the session: `$authService->getStorage()->write($identity);`

Has anyone been able to get the ZfcRbac queries to cache without having to extend the module and implement caching in my own variants?

Answer (score 2):

ZfcRbac currently does not have any caching mechanism for roles and permissions. This is something I want to implement for a future version of ZfcRbac!